# WPF binding Data into ListBox multiple columns

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, listbox

//Hi! I need to put my data into listBox with multiple columns I saw this link [stackoverflow.com...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220502/wpf-bind-list-to-multi-column-listbox) but it talks about every thing without mention the way that I can Add Items into the columns would you please just explain how to add Data Items into columns and thanks a lot.I did the following things successfully

```
<ListView.View>
     <GridView>
         <GridView.Columns>
              <GridViewColumn Header="1" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Field1}" />
              <GridViewColumn Header="2" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Field2}" />
              <GridViewColumn Header="3" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Field3}" />
         </GridView.Columns>
     </GridView>
</ListView.View>`

 public sealed class MyListBoxItem
    {
        public string Field1 { get; set; }
        public string Field2 { get; set; }
        public string Field3 { get; set; }
    }
    public sealed class MyViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<MyListBoxItem> Items { get; private set; }
        public MyViewModel()
        {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<MyListBoxItem>();
            Items.Add(new MyListBoxItem { Field1 = "One", Field2 = "Two", Field3 = "Three" });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for Editing I was trying to make it like this but I couldn't ;)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set the `DataContext` property of your `Window` (say it is Window1) that contains the `ListBox` control, inside the Window1.xaml.cs class's constructor like this:

```
public Window1()
{
    MyViewModel vm = new MyViewModel();

    this.DataContext = vm;
}
```

Next step is to set the `ItemsSource` property of your ListBox control (inside `XAML`) to the `Items` property that you have made available inside your ViewModel class:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
    <!--Other XAML-->
</ListBox>
```

Additionally, you should also implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface for your `MyListBoxItem` class which is explained [here in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx). This is because implementing `MVVM` pattern in your WPF app. requires that you implement change notifications for `oneway` or `twoway` databindings to work (see this to learn more on [DataBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx)).

Here is a more detailed explanation of [MVVM on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx).